# Not receiving emails from DocuSIgn SandBox when envelope created through the API

Tags: docusignapi

When I upload a document using the Docusign API on the Sandbox and then send the document I do not receive any emails.

I've also logged on to the sandbox and tried to sign the document but don't have the option - status seems to be waiting for others (even though the document is only sent to my email).

When I create the envelope through the web site and send, I do get the email.
This has only started to happen in the last day or two. Had been working fine for us.

Is there a problem with Sandbox?

Comment: Can you please post the JSON from your request

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page (stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question

Comment: I had exactly the same issue with you. I'm developing using python with https://pydocusign.readthedocs.io/en/latest/demo.html#embedded-signing. The envelope successfully created but I didn't receive the email and the status was `Waiting for others`

Comment: @CodingDawg should I create new question regarding this issue to be specific in python?

Answer (score 6):

The issue was that we were passing the ClientUserId property for the Signer in the API call when creating the envelope.
I wasn't aware but this actually stops the notification emails being sent.

Comment: Ahh thank you for the clue, I removed `ClientUserId` and I received the email. What is `ClientUserId` used for anyway?

Comment: ClientUserId indicates that the recipient is an Embedded Recipient. https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign

Answer (score 0):

You can check Docusign system status at

https://trust.docusign.com/en-us/system-status/

Answer (score 0):

When I wasn't received emails in the develop environment, it was because I hadn't set:

```
{ "status": "sent" }
```

...in the envelope definition. This is the documented way of indicating that you would like this envelope to be sent rather than just "created", which sets it as a draft.